# Stop peeking at empty stack

Tags: java, stack, compare

I'm checking that a stack is sorted by popping it and comparing the pop to the peek. If the pop is greater than the peek, we know those two elements are in order. I run this loop as long as the stack isn't empty.

The problem I'm running into is with the final element of the stack. I do my final pop, and but it tries to peek at an empty stack to make sure it's in order. Since there is nothing there, I get a runtime error.

```
public static boolean isSorted(Stack<Integer> s){
boolean result = true;

while(!s.empty()){
    if(s.pop() < s.peek()){
        result = false;
    }
}

return result;
}
```

I'm trying to do this exclusively with Stack, so using only push pop and peek. Nothing from an ArrayList. How can I fix this problem, while still checking every element?

I've tried storing pop in a temporary variable, but that fixed nothing. Not sure what I was hoping for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you need two items, but `empty()` checks for just one item. Once you call `pop()`, you need to do another `empty()` call prior to executing a `peek()`:

```
while(!s.empty()){
    // We know we have one element available; store it in "top"
    Integer top = s.pop();
    // If the next element is not available, exit 
    if (s.empty()) {
        break;
    }
    if(top < s.peek()){
        // Once result is set to "false", it never becomes "true"
        // so we might as well return now:
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: I actually tried something like that as well, but I still got the error. I'll give it another shot and let you know how it goes.

Comment: given that you're answer sticks to the stack only, as well as gives a solid explanation, I'm choosing this as the right answer. Thank you!

Comment: I should have included that I do not want to alter the original stack. Your solution does that, but given it was not requested that's no problem. Where in the loop would you push the values into a secondary stack?

Comment: @JeffreyDilley The problem with pushing on a secondary stack is that the resulting stack would be the reversed copy of the original stack.

Comment: not if you push that stack back into the original before the return :) Which I just did, and it worked fine.

Comment: Storing the popped values in steck, I just did `while (!steck.empty()){
      s.push(steck.pop());
     }`

Answer (score 0):

It has to, as `pop` removes the last element and `peek` throws `EmptyStackException` if the stack is empty

```
public static boolean isSorted(Stack<Integer> s){
boolean result = true;
while(!s.empty()){
    if(s.size() == 1)
        return result;
    if(s.pop() < s.peek()){
        result = false;
    }
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: Not sure I see the purpose of `result`, why not `return false;` when `if (s.pop() < s.peek())` and `true` at the end of the method? Also, this method empties the input `Stack`... so it *was* sorted or not...

Comment: @Shady Atef, that uses s.size. That is an inherited method from ArrayList. I'm going stack only

Comment: @JeffreyDilley, Stack in Java is based on `Vector`, So I think it's not a problem if you used an inherited method.
Also any data structure must have a way to know the size of it..

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes you'r right, I just didn't want to alter the original code so much.

Comment: I was avoiding inhereted methods though. You're answer was correct.

Comment: What about a stack in c++, those don't inherit from vector, do they?

Comment: @JeffreyDilley in C++ especially GNU compiler, stack is just a wrapper around other containers.
It defaults to `deque` and maybe set to `vector`. or a custom one withe few conditions

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, is to check the size explicitly:

```
while(s.size() > 1){ // ok, we have enough elements in the stack
    if (s.pop() < s.peek()) {
        result = false;
        break; // no need to proceed, we already know it's not sorted.
    }
}
```